# Significato di "ipotesto" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Parola di Dante* di Luca Serianni ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Tra le più precoci citazioni di Dante ci sono tre luoghi del volgarizzamento dell’*Eneide* del senese Ciampolo di Meo degli Ugurgieri, probabilmente risalente agli anni 1315-1321; eccone uno, la descrizione di Cerbero (*Eneide*, VI 417-421), che è notoriamente l’**ipotesto** della rielaborazione dantesca, ﻿di cui Ciampolo cita puntualmente le parole: «Cerberus haec ingens latratu regna trifauci / personat» → «Cerbero, fera crudele e diversa, con tre gole caninamente latra» (cfr. *Inf*., 6 13-14).

Non sono sicura di capire cosa significhi "ipotesto" nel contesto del brano citato. Immagino abbia a che vedere con il fatto che Dante si sia basato sull'*Eneide* di Virgilio per fare la sua descrizione di Cerbero.

Sul [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/I/ipotesto.html) ho trovato

> L'insieme del materiale testuale che sta alla base di un ipertesto.

Tuttavia, questa accezione, così come quella di "ipertesto" nello stesso vocabolario, sembrano  fare riferimento esclusivamente all'ambito dell'informatica.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "ipotesto" in questo contesto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Il termine *ipotesto* è tecnico; il termine *ipertesto* è usato nel dizionario con un significato tecnico che non è immediato ricondurre a quello comune di documento informatico con i collegamenti. Hai indovinato il significato.

---

Quello che ho capito con una piccola ricerca (invito a verificare perché non sono uno studioso di letteratura):

È gergo tecnico di una disciplina chiamata [intertestualità](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertestualit%C3%A0); nello specifico, questa dualità fra ipertesto e ipotesto è intesa nel senso descritto da Gérard Genette in *Palimpsestes: La Littérature au second dégré*.

Capitolo I:

> J’ai délibérément différé la mention du quatrième type de transtextualité parce que c’est lui et lui seul qui nous occupera directement ici. C’est donc lui que je rebaptise désormais hypertextualité. J’entends par là toute relation unissant un texte B (que j’appellerai hypertexte ) à un texte antérieur A (que j’appellerai, bien sûr, hypotexte) sur lequel il se greffe d’une manière qui n’est pas celle du commentaire.

Capitolo II:

> J'appelle donc hypertexte tout texte dérivé d'un texte antérieur par transformation simple (nous dirons désormais transformation tout court) ou par transformation indirecte: nous dirons imitation.

Genette definisce *ipertestualità* la situazione in cui un testo (ipertesto) deriva da un testo antecedente (ipotesto) tramite una *trasformazione (semplice)* o un'*imitazione*, e postula che deva essere una forma diversa dal *commento* letterario in senso stretto (che chiama *metatestualità*). Gli archetipi di queste due forme di ipertestualità, come spiega nel Capitolo I, sono:

- per la trasformazione, *Ulisse* di James Joyce, dove le vicende dell'*Odissea* sono trasportate a Dublino.
- per l'imitazione, *Eneide* di Virgilio, dove delle vicende vengono raccontate in modo da ricordare lo stile e i fatti dell'*Odissea*.

> Ou plus brutalement : Joyce raconte l’histoire d’Ulysse d’une autre manière qu’Homère, Virgile raconte l’histoire d’Enée à la manière d’Homère; transformations symétriques et inverses.

Comment: Interessante... Grazie alla tua risposta ho trovato [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=59Grgq6Y-DcC&pg=PA9&dq=intertestualit%C3%A0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij-fbQtLT1AhULHxoKHWuWCwAQ6AF6BAgBEAE#v=onepage&q=ipo&f=false) in cui tutti questi concetti vengono spiegati abbastanza bene. Sentiti libero di usare questa fonte per aggiungere quello che vuoi al tuo post.